# Scrolling on top of position fixed element does not scroll container

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, mousewheel

I have a problem not being able to scroll on top of a position fixed element, inside a container with overflow:scroll.

```
.container {overflow: scroll; height: 200px;}
.right {position: fixed;}
.left {height: 2000px;}
```

Consider this example: [jsfiddle](http://codepen.io/rafaelcode/pen/mRBWZp).

If you scroll anywhere inside the container, the page scrolls. However, if you scroll with the cursor on top of the fixed element (content right fixed), the container does not scroll.

Any ideas?

EDIT

I also need to be able to click the content right fixed, as it is a button going back to the previous page. Hence, `z-index: -1;` wont work.

EDIT EDIT

I found a solution. By using [jQuery mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) and giving the container a scroll based on the mousewheel function of the .right class, it works just fine. See updated [jsfiddle](http://codepen.io/rafaelcode/pen/mRBWZp), the jQuery mousewheel is directly included in the js.

Answer (score 1):

An element set to `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` is no longer considered to be inside its parent container.

When the mouse cursor is above the `fixed` element, it is trying to scroll on the outermost document, which is not tall enough to require scrolling.

If you resize the output section of your CodePen to be shorter than the height of the content you currently have there, then try scrolling on top of the `fixed` element, you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* expected behavior - but you can *fix* this pushing the `right` behind the `container` in the *stacking order* by adding `z-index: -1` to it. But you won't be able to click the link in the `right` then.

See the demo below:

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.left, .right {
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
  height: 2000px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  position: fixed;
  border: 3px solid red;
  left: 60%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    content left
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="right">
    content right fixed
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. The content on the right-hand side is a button, going back to the previous page, therefore needing to be clickable. Hence, `z-index: -1;` wont work

Comment: yeah, that's right... but I guess there are no options here... Let us know here if you find one. Thanks! :)

Comment: that's a nice one :)